# Web Api Get Request with class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to Web API, and I'm stuck at getting multiple values for `Get()`. What I'm trying to do is to pass in many values through the query string. Instead of having a `Get(string .., string .., so on)`, I decided to go MVC style and do something like `Get(RequestModel m)`. This returns a NullRef exception. e.g.:

For my 'web request', I've created a class:

```
RequestModel
{
    public string Req1 {get;set;}
    public string Req2 {get;set;}
    public string Req3 {get;set;}
}
```

My Get function in the controller:

```
public ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public Get(RequestModel m)
    {
        return m.Req1;
    }
}
```

My url is:

```
http://localhost/api/values?Req1=test
```

Is this possible? If not, what's the best way to do this? The only thing i can think of as an alternative is `ParseQueryString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to explicitly set [FromUri] attribute like below:

public Get(**[FromUri]** RequestModel m)